# How to parse and aggregate values in a list of list

Tags: python, parsing, aggregate

I have a list of lists in a `txt` file (example below), and I'm trying to define the attributes and assign them values.

For example,

```
"Harry Potter" = book(string), "2000" = year(int), and "900" = pages(int).
```

=>

```
[['Harry Potter', 2000, 900], ['Hunger Games', 2004, 850]]
```

How to parse and aggregate values?

Comment: Is that exactly what your file looks like? Could you show 2 or 3 more lines? I think the csv module might work for this but I personally would use regex.

Comment: "Harry Potter" and "Hunger Games" are books in a txt file which contain information about them, such as pages and year. I'm attempting to make a constructor which needs to parse and aggregate the values before being able to sort the information

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you are trying to parse and extract the quoted data, you could simply employ regex and use findall for your purpose

```
import re
re.findall(r'"(.*?)"', line)
['Harry Potter', '2000', '900']
```

Moreover, over and above that, you would like to interpret numbers as numbers, you can also apply some post processing to the parsed data

```
[int(elem) if elem.isdigit() else elem for elem in re.findall(r'"(.*?)"', line)]
['Harry Potter', 2000, 900]
```